# Exception of type "System.OutOfMemoryException" deploying database to Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure

I installed SQL Server Express 2017 on a VM in Azure and restored my 2 Gig Kentico 9 database to it.
Then I tried to deploy to an Azure database.
Things seemed to be going well for 30 minutes, then I got an error 
[image]

[Update]

I increased the memory in the virtual machine and the spec of the destination database then tried again, but I got the same error at the same table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this SSMS running out of memory. SSMS is a 32bit app so only has access to 2GB of address space. You would be better off using a tool like [Data Migration Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595) or exporting your DB to a BACPAC file and then restoring this to Azure SQL.

Comment: I was able to create a BACPAC file but not import it.
https://serverfault.com/questions/909661/exception-of-type-system-outofmemoryexception-importing-bacpac-into-azure