# Exception of type “System.OutOfMemoryException” importing BacPac into Azure

Tags: azure

Because of [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/909536/exception-of-type-system-outofmemoryexception-deploying-database-to-azure) I thought I would try importing a BACPAC file into Azure SQL Server.

When I try and import a Data Tier Application ( a BACPAC file) to a new Azure database I get an out of memory exception.

[image]

When I ran the Data Migration Assistant I get 1 unsupported feature
Azure SQL Database does not support trace flags

I wonder if that is why I get that error
[image]

Comment: Try closing SSMS and reopening it and trying the import again. I have found that if you have previously run some very large select statements that returned millions of rows the SSMS process is already using a lot of memory and more easily gets OutOfMemory errors. So closing and reopening SSMS helps avoid this.

Comment: @GregGalloway nice suggestion. I was seeing the exact same problem, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Posting as an answer due to the popularity of the comment...

Try closing SSMS and reopening it and trying the import again. I have found that if you have previously run some very large select statements that returned millions of rows the SSMS process is already using a lot of memory and more easily gets OutOfMemory errors. So closing and reopening SSMS helps avoid this.

The `System.OutOfMemoryException` is a .NET error which usually means the SSMS client tool is out of memory not that the server is out of memory.

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered a similar issue when importing a 1TB BacPac file into the Azure SQL Database.

The solution which worked was to:

- Create Azure VM with 64GB of RAM (D16ds_v4) - temporary VM for restore process
- Attach 4TB managed disk to the Azure VM, format it and mount as drive T:
- Transfer BacPac file into the VM
- Download [64-bit SqlPackage for .Net Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-download?view=sql-server-ver15) command-line tool into the Azure VM
- Run the following in the command prompt (with QuickEdit disabled) inside the Azure VM:

```
mkdir T:\Temp
SET TEMP=T:\Temp
SET TMP=T:\Temp
sqlpackage.exe /a:import /tcs:"Data Source=[ServerName].database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=[DatabaseName];User Id=[UserName];Password=[Password]" /sf:E:\BacPacDir\BacPacFile.bacpac /p:DatabaseEdition=Hyperscale /p:DatabaseServiceObjective=HS_Gen5_2
```

- Change E:\BacPacDir\BacPacFile.bacpac to the location of your bacpac.
- Change Azure SQL Database parameters accordingly: /p:DatabaseEdition=Hyperscale /p:DatabaseServiceObjective=HS_Gen5_2
- For the Standard/Premium SQL DB there is an additional DatabaseMaximumSize parameter: /p:DatabaseEdition=Premium /p:DatabaseServiceObjective=P11 /p:DatabaseMaximumSize=1024

Comment: i dislike that, you reference your blog instead write the full answer

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This really does seem to be the problem, restoring a bacpac on local server that's over 1gb in size create the out of memory exception in SQL MS. Downloading SqlPackage and running from the command line works every time. This should be considered an answer.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try is to import the Bacpac file using the Azure portal rather than the database. You would upload the Bacpac to Azure storage using a tool like [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/features/storage-explorer/), then point the portal to that to import it - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-import